# Does JAX-RS Support Input Streaming?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Given the following HTML:

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

If I have a JAX-RS method that starts with:

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(
   @FormParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
   ...
}
```

Is `uploadedInputStream` going to be streamed as part of the *Java EE API Specification*, not implementation specific?  That is I can upload a 1TB file without blowing up the heap?

I can't seem to find anything that shows it is standard, even support for   `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` is implementation specific.

The only thing I can think of to make it work across app servers is to use a servlet like the following that will display the number of bytes uploaded.

```
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig
public class ImportServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req,
    final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

        int c = 0;
        InputStream cis = req.getPart("file").getInputStream();
        int ch = cis.read();
        while (ch != -1) {
            ++c;
            ch = cis.read();
        }
        cis.close();
        resp.getWriter().print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Multipart support is not standardized in JAX-RS. You will need to dig into implementation specific features to handle it.

Comment: Curious: how would a servlet help you? A file upload is still going to be part of one massive raw HTTP request before it is transformed into a HttpServletRequest and passed along to you or the FileUpload API you're using. Did I miss something in the JEE spec developments that allows you to stream it in even after the request has already been processed?

Comment: Even if it gets transformed it already breaks it apart and puts it into temporary storage using the @MultipartConfig annotation.  I have updated my question to show how I would do it using Servlets

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, multipart data streams are loaded off to disk and then wrapped for you. Can you rather user direct `PUT` requests? It will give you direct access to the input stream from the client. I tried this with gigabytes of data without problems.

If someone knows better, please correct me.